# Return all matching css from string

Tags: php, css, string, extract, string-matching

I've a shopify css file with the following content:

```
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.136d99375282ffb6ea8c3dc4a8fe189c7be691b2.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.399ae4c4dd52d38e3f3214ec0cc9c61a0a67ea08.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.29e3afeb38a0ba35e784cf169a40e8beaf814daa.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.e7c533c4afbed28070f6ac45dbcfe6f37840c0a8.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")
}.slick-slider{position:relative;display:block;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-ms-touch-action:pan-y;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}
....
....
```

I want to extract only @font-face styles from above string using PHP. The result should be like:

```
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.136d99375282ffb6ea8c3dc4a8fe189c7be691b2.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.399ae4c4dd52d38e3f3214ec0cc9c61a0a67ea08.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.29e3afeb38a0ba35e784cf169a40e8beaf814daa.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.e7c533c4afbed28070f6ac45dbcfe6f37840c0a8.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")
}
```

Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under these conditions the solution would be `$thingYouWant = explode('.slick-slider', $input)[0]`. But I don't think that's what you need. So maybe provide a bit more context?

Comment: No that's not what I want. I need all css classes having @font-face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/qhI7TN/1):

```
/\@font\-face\{.*}/sU
```

which will match a string that starts with "@font-face{" and ends with "}" with any characters in between. The "s" flag will make the match accept line breaks for the placeholder ".". The "U" flag will make the matching "Ungreedy", searching for short matches rather than long matches.

Usage in PHP:

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOT
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.136d99375282ffb6ea8c3dc4a8fe189c7be691b2.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.399ae4c4dd52d38e3f3214ec0cc9c61a0a67ea08.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.29e3afeb38a0ba35e784cf169a40e8beaf814daa.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.e7c533c4afbed28070f6ac45dbcfe6f37840c0a8.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")
}.slick-slider{position:relative;display:block;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-ms-touch-action:pan-y;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}
EOT;

$fonts = []; 

preg_match_all("/\@font\-face\{.*}/sU", $input, $fonts);

foreach ($fonts[0] as $font)
{
    echo ($font);
    echo ("\n");
    echo ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regular expressions for this. Code:

```
<?php

$str = '@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.136d99375282ffb6ea8c3dc4a8fe189c7be691b2.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.399ae4c4dd52d38e3f3214ec0cc9c61a0a67ea08.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.29e3afeb38a0ba35e784cf169a40e8beaf814daa.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.e7c533c4afbed28070f6ac45dbcfe6f37840c0a8.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}
@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")
}.slick-slider{position:relative;display:block;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-ms-touch-action:pan-y;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}
....
....';
preg_match_all('/@font-face\{[^\}]*\}/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

And result will be:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.136d99375282ffb6ea8c3dc4a8fe189c7be691b2.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n6.399ae4c4dd52d38e3f3214ec0cc9c61a0a67ea08.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}' (length=347)
  1 => string '@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:400;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.29e3afeb38a0ba35e784cf169a40e8beaf814daa.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n4.e7c533c4afbed28070f6ac45dbcfe6f37840c0a8.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}' (length=347)
  2 => string '@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")}' (length=347)
  3 => string '@font-face{font-family:"Work Sans";font-weight:700;font-style:normal;src:url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.35eac55373d3da50c529c81066eb2f2f0fbedb82.woff2?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff2"),url("https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/work_sans/worksans_n7.1b010d40a44f517d5363112c4aff386332758bc9.woff?&hmac=xxxxxxxxxx") format("woff")
}' (length=348)
```